# how to get ssd and hdd size in gb of a windows computer using python?

Tags: python

I have created an exe using pyinstaller.

In  which I want to know the size of the SSD and HDD which are installed in the users system.

expected output in the below format
{
"hdd_size": "1.8TB",
"sdd_size": "476GB"
}
How can I get these informations?

Comment: Well the *duplicate* does not say a word about which disks are installed... If you need that `psutil.disk_partitions()` will give it to you.

Answer (score 1):

if u want to know the size of the disk, u can try this lib (psutil) i think psutil may help u

```
import psutil
disk_usage = psutil.disk_usage("C:\\")
```

Comment: @itslvanpsk i have used psutil but it always give me a size of ssd not hdd. is there any way to find a data in below format using python.    {"hdd_size":"1.8TB","ssd_size":"476GB"}

Comment: If the return is an dict you can pick it up, try to save this '{"hdd_size":"1.8TB","ssd_size":"476GB"}' into a dict and use 'print(dict_name["hdd_size"])' I think this will resolve your problem

Comment: @ItslvanPsk using psutil i can find the size but how will i determine whether drive is ssd or hdd drive.